# Including texts between boxplots

Tags: r, text, legend, boxplot

I would like to include the pvalues (`pvaul`) between each pair of boxplots.

`pval`:

```
V1
0.003
0.05
0.001
```

boxplot(count ~ spray,data = InsectSprays,axes=F,ylim=c(0,30))

[image]

I expect in the output something like that:
[image]

Some ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at `help("text")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would do it. Change cex for point size.

```
x<-c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6)  
y<-c(3,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,8)  

boxplot(x,y)  
legend('top',legend=c("0.05"), cex=.90, bty= "n")
```